# What is the correct way to make an API without a model behind it?

Tags: django, django-views, django-serializer

Suppose I want to make an API that is not supported by a model. Certain fields are entered with the request, some processing is applied, and then other fields are returned.

The way I usually use it is to define a simple view that instantiates a serializer to do the validation. And then I return the fields directly from the view, for example with a JSONResponse.

Is this the right way to do it? Does it make sense to use a serializer for validation? Is it better to use a form? Should the response be serialized? Is it correct to process the input data in the view?

Comment: serializer.Serializer is the correct method to use in such cases where you specify the fields you want without resorting to a model. Whether using a serializer makes sense depend on the application. Suppose you are working with requests coming from the frontend/mobile side, in that case it is recommended that you serialize the data to avoid format mismatches between different programming languages.